# ! Undefined control sequence. \reserved@b ->C:\Users l.69 \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I'm running `\documentclass{beamer}` on pdfstudio in Windows 10. When I compile appears an error in many frames, and I can't find out where is the error, the error line 69 refers to:

```
\section{Descripción Tema y Motivación}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Descripción Tema y Motivación}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
%\vspace{-13.41pt}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pending}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

and the error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ->C:\Users 
                       \eric .sanchez\Desktop \IFOP _investigador\ppt \figur...
l.69 \end{frame}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Thanks in advance for any help, Eric

Comment: Can you try with a figure without special characters like `_` or spaces in its name or path?

Comment: Off topic, but you do not need floating specifier such as `[h!]` in a beamer document.

Comment: Thank you!. Removing spaces or _ didn't work. thank you for 2nd advice. Third comment worked!

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have a `\graphicspath` command that uses backslashes in its argument. Replace them by slashes (e.g `C:/Users`).

And if possible avoid absolute pathes, normally they are not a good idea.